# 'Catch exception' extension on Task class

Tags: c#, exception

I have code like this:

```
try { await myFunc(); }
catch (MyException ex) 
{
    switch (ex.Code)
    {
        case 1: ... break;
        case 2: ... break;
        ...
    }
}
```

And was wondering is it possible to make all that look something like this:

```
...
{
    await myFunc().HandleMyExeptions(OnMyException);
}

private void OnMyException(int exCode)
{
    switch (ex.Code)
    {
        case 1: ... break;
        case 2: ... break;
        ...
    }
}
```

where I would create extension class for tasks something like this

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static void HandleErrors(this Task task, Action<int> handleError)
    {
        // I don't know what would go here nor whether the header of 
        // this function is a step in a good direction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to look something like this:

```
public static Task HandleErrors(this Task task, Action<int> handleError) =>
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted && t.Exception.InnerException is MyException ex)
        {
            handleError(ex.Code);
        }
    });
```

Had you provided sample code in your question that showed how your existing exception handling worked, then I would have fully tested this, but you didn't. If you care to write that code and add it to your question, then I'll do the testing.

---

A simpler approach using `await`:

```
public static async Task HandleErrors(this Task task, Action<int> handleError)
{
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (MyException ex)
    {
        handleError(ex.Code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've edited your code minimally, and it works like a charm! No need, but thank you for your kind suggestion!

Comment: No worries. Be careful calling this on the same task multiple times. It will run each time even though the task runs only once.

Comment: I recommend using `await` instead of `ContinueWith` for reasons described [on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary - Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yes. `await` has fewer corner cases than the low-level `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @Charlieface: No; that was the behavior during an early preview of `async`, but they changed that before it was released. Now all exceptions propagated from an `async` method result in a faulted task being returned (or a previously-returned task faulting), regardless of whether they're before the first `await` or not.

Comment: @StephenCleary Apparently you're right as usual https://dotnetfiddle.net/dOI7du